# No. of real roots of $2^x = 1+x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

No. of real roots of $2^x = 1+x^3$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $f(x)=2^x-x^3-1\;,$ Then $f'(x)=2^x\cdot \ln(2)-3x^2$

and $f''(x)=2^{x}\cdot (\ln 2)^2-6x$ and $f'''(x)=2^x\cdot (\ln2)^3-6$ and $f''''(x)=2^x\cdot (\ln 2)^4>0\; \forall\;  x\in \mathbb{R}$

So $f''''(x) = 0$ has no real roots. So using $\bf{LMVT}$, The equation $f'''(x)=0$ has at most one real

roots. So $f''(x) = 0$ has $2$  at most real roots. So $f'(x) = 0$ has $3$ at most  real roots. So $f(x)=0$

has at most at most $4$ real roots.

Here $x=0$ and $x=1$ are two integer roots

But How can i find that $f(x)=0$ has exactly $4$ real roots

Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You showed there are at most 4 real roots. You can show there are at least 4 real roots by using the continuity of $f(x)$ and showing four intervals where it changes sign. Show and use these facts:

$$f(-1)>0$$
$$f \left(-\frac 12 \right)<0$$
$$f \left(\frac 12 \right)>0$$
$$f(2)<0$$
$$f(10)>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me add something :

$f'''(x)$ is continuous and monotonous in $\mathbb{R}$, and we have :  $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f''''(x)>0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=-6, \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$$  using LMVT the equation $f'''(x)=0$ has only one solution in $\mathbb{R}$, using the same method until we get $f(x)=0$ has exactly $4$ solutions $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.